# Where does the stored procedure Sys.xp_readerrorlog Read its contents from specifically?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, logging

I have been working with this stored procedure Sys.xp_readerrorlog for around a week now, and what I have learned is it accepts 7 parameters to fully refine how it should display its data. Easily enough to understand.

I have the question now from, where exactly does this stored procedure get its data from? I know you can also preview the data in the SSMS Object browser, under Managements In the SQL Server logs folder, although I have come to the theory that the Dialog that opens when you read the logs also use this procedure to display to the user in a grid.

I am baffled. I scouted through the system databases and found nothing (no table) which looks remotely like the output you get from this procedure

```
exec sys.xp_readerrorlog 1,0,'','',null,null,N'Desc';
```

Any expert that can tell me where the actual log data is stored, and if it is queryable through a select statement if you have admin rights?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It reads from the [SQL Server error log file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187885.aspx), which is a plain text file. There is no built-in interface to the file from TSQL; xp_readerrorlog is widely known, but it's also undocumented so relying on it is risky although of course you can [use it](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1476/reading-the-sql-server-log-files-using-tsql/) if you don't mind that risk.

Using SMO you can find the file [location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server.errorlogpath.aspx) but there is no special API for reading it because it's just a text file.

Comment: Did not expect that coming, really thought it was stored in an internal database, but curiosity piqued, and I felt the need to ask. I have code to extract it into a temporary table, manipulate it using the internal parameters and the PATINDEX() method, and to bulk copy it to another table which has another column layout.

Comment: I guess the idea is that SQL Server needs a 'failsafe' location for logging, e.g. if there's a fatal error during startup then the system databases might not even be online and available. (Gets off lawn.)